# Clear new lines in Docx VBA

Tags: vba, docx

I need to delete all of new lines if is consecutive, i know macros in excel but not in word, how can i read the value of an entire line?

I read all the lines in the doc with this:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Next i
```

Is there other way of read each line or how to know the total lines in a word to put this in the for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to delete all of new lines if is consecutive

Each blank line is actually a paragraph, so:

```
Sub RemoveBlankParas()
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Len(para.Range.Text) = 1 Then
            'only the paragraph mark, so..
            para.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

However, if there are only two consecutive blank paragraphs then using `ReplaceAll` is easier and quicker. Here's a recorded macro that can be tidied up:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Word's Find/Replace feature uses a primitive form of regular expressions, so the following reduces two or more consecutive paragraph marks. NB `MatchWildcards = True` to use regex:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(^13)\1@"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

[Word regular expressions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/putting-regular-expressions-to-work-in-word-HA001087304.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087305)